# Finding smallest average of length between two sets of coordinates

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Let's say I have two lists of coordination (same count on both lists) and we have to assign each coordinate from set A to one coordinate in list B. what is the best approach to get minimum average length from selecting this combination.
for example in the situation like bellow:

[image: example]
an obvious solution would be to assign red(1) to black(2) and red(2) to black(3) and red(3) to black(4) and red(4) to black(1). but it's not the answer because the average length of these 4 combinations is higher than the solution that would be assigning red(1) to black(1) and red(2) to black(2) and red(3) to black(3) and red(4) to black(4).

my thought is to loop through each combination of two sets and measure the average distance of each combination and finally select minimum avg, but it's not certainly the best and optimal solution.
is there a better way to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Both sets of points can be completely dispatched randomly, But one thing is that points can spawn one after the other, for example first we have one black and one red point, then one black and one red point adds and so on

Comment: I have to sit down and think about this when I wake up tomorrow but just as the first thought, a stable marriage kind of solution comes to mind. You start by assigning 1 -> 1 and update the pairing when something "better" comes along. However I can't say without going through a few cases, if this gives the optimal solution in all cases. Another thought is if you can modify the good old closest pair problem while keeping the O(nlgn^2) -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/ Some amount of memoization to adapt it for all pairs perhaps.

Comment: are your points aligned as in your example or are they dispatched randomly in the plane? an idea (to avoid the cartesian product) may be to consider the planar graphs (where edges are not crossing since we could "decross" them to get an lesser sum)

Comment: both sets of points can be completely dispatched randomly.

Comment: **BUT** one thing is that points can spawn one after the other, for example first we have one black and one red point, then one black and one red point adds and so on. IDK if I did clear what I meant.

Comment: Looks like a "stable marriage" problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem (or related: "stable roommates")

Comment: What time complexity you want ? what about N*(2^N)

Comment: well, originally I want this for developing a game but as it is very performance consuming, especially when there are a lot of nodes, I gave up on finding the most optimized answer and implement a simulation of a near enough optimized result. for now, I'm just curies about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would be similar to the Gale-Shapley Algorithm. Of course this problem assumes that for each coordinate we know the distance from that coordinate to every other coordinate. Assuming that a list is provided and in sorted order from the coordinates closest to furthest from the coordinate in question.

Then the algorithm would be as follows

While there is a coordinate **c** who has not been assigned to any other coordinate:

```
    Choose that coordinate **c** 
    Let **a** be the closest coordinate to **c** that has not been assigned 
    If **a** has not been assigned then **a** and **c** are assigned to each other 
    Else **a** is already assigned **c'**
            if **a** is closer to **c'** than **c**, then **c** remains unassigned
            else if **a** is closer to c than c', then a and **c** are assigned to each other and **c'** becomes unassigned
            endif
    endif
```

return the set of assigned pairs

Proof by contradiction: always matched

- suppose not. Suppose **c** is free but has tried to be assigned to every **a**
- then every a must already be assigned (bc the algorithm requires that once an a is assigned it must remain in some assignment for the rest of the algorithm)

  - if all *n* a's are in assignment pairs then there must be *n* c's in assignment pairs
  - Both lists have the same count
  - Contradiction, c cannot be free

Proof by Contradiction: Check that the assignment is smallest average

- Suppose not. Suppose the average is not as small as it could be
- (a1,c1) (a2,c2) a1 and c2 are closer to each other than their current matches
- the algorithm states for those pairs to be possible a1 must have tried to be assigned c1
- Did a1 ever try to be assigned to c2?

  - if not, then c1 is closer to a1 than c2
  - if so, then c2 must have rejected a1's assignment because c2 was already assigned to a closer coordinate
- Contradiction, the coordinates will always be matched to closest coordinate available

Time complexity: O(n^2) because there are n x n possible pairs and in the worst case the while loop would terminate after n^2 iterations